# C# window form.(stimul $exception, hidden [Expression is not supported while IntelliTrace debugging])

Tags: c#

```
     private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         try
         {

             İnvoiceClass i = new İnvoiceClass();
             i.Order_Pics = orderpics;
             i.RegDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
             if (checkBox2.Checked)
             {
                 i.İsCheckedOut = true;
                 i.CeackOutDate = DateTime.Now.Date;
             }
             else
             {
                 i.İsCheckedOut = false;
             }

             DialogResult res = messaage.MShows("Kayıt", "Fişden Çıktı Almak istermısın?", bll.Create(i, custumer, products, user), MType.yesorno, MLogo.info);
             if (res == DialogResult.Yes)
             {
                 StiReport sti = new StiReport();

                 sti.Load(@"C:\Users\emir\Documents\projeter1\Report22.mrt");
                 if (sti == null || label19.Text == string.Empty || label27.Text == string.Empty || label22.Text == string.Empty || label10.Text == string.Empty || label17.Text == string.Empty || bll.Readinvnum() == string.Empty || products == null)
                 {

                 }
                 elseenter image description here
                 {
                     sti.Dictionary.Variables["Date"].Value = label19.Text;
                     

                     sti.Render(); //$exception, hidden [Expression is not supported while IntelliTrace debugging]
                     sti.Show();
                 }

             }
             text_clear();
         }
         catch (Exception a)
         {
             messaage.MShows("Bilgi", "Sipariş oluşturur ken bir sorun oluştu!!", a.Message, MType.ok, MLogo.info);
         }
         textBox1.Enabled = true;
         textBox2.Enabled = false;
         textBox3.Enabled = false;
         productlist.Clear();
         dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
         dataGridView1.DataSource = bll.readall();
         dataGridView1.Columns["id"].Visible = false;
     }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/prwmd.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4naK.png)   Hello, it is about a sale in C# window form app. I'm trying to print the invoice I created with stimulsoft, but I get this error  (stimul $exception, hidden [Expression is not supported while IntelliTrace debugging])

I searched the search engine and couldn't figure it out. Is there anyone to help?